# cleanup and burn "members"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

[members](/questions/tagged/members) on Stack Overflow (115 questions, no tag wiki) needs to go!

IMO, questions about class members in OO languages should be retagged to [member](/questions/tagged/member), the tag should be removed where it's talking about website membership systems, and perhaps a synonym added to point to [member](/questions/tagged/member) (which itself probably needs cleanup to get it off questions that aren't about OOP; there seem to be a few about set membership, etc.).

[membership](/questions/tagged/membership) seems to have similar problems as well.

Comment: Long have I thought thinning the herd would prove usef.... oh, that's not what you meant.

Comment: for class members, there is an excellent tag called, well... **[tag:class-members]**