# Should the "member" and "class-members" tags be merged, or do they have different meanings?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Looking at the tag wiki for [member](/questions/tagged/member), I read the following:

> A member is an element of an object in the object-oriented programming paradigm. Member variables are often called fields, while member functions are also called methods.

For [class-members](/questions/tagged/class-members), I read the following:

> This tag refers to members of a class in object-oriented language. These are fields, constructors, destructors, methods and, usually in higher-level languages, properties and events.

Should the tags be merged, or does the latter refers to what in some programming languages are static methods/properties?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182971/cleanup-and-burn-members

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say no.

- Not all languages that have members have classes—e.g. JavaScript.
- Some languages with classes also have members on objects that are not classes—e.g. `struct`'s in C#.

So while they're very close, they are not quite identical. If you wanted to ask a question about enumerating the members of an object in JavaScript, you definitely would not use the [class-members](/questions/tagged/class-members) tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say they should be merged. While they are technically different, as pswg points out, [member](/questions/tagged/member) is the superset of [class-members](/questions/tagged/class-members), and looking at how many questions are tagged [member](/questions/tagged/member) versus [class-members](/questions/tagged/class-members) it's obvious that [member](/questions/tagged/member) is much more commonly used.

Even though the more common tags (like [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)) have class members, [class-members](/questions/tagged/class-members) is not used for most related questions.  There also aren't very many instances where having two tags would be helpful; [member](/questions/tagged/member) seems like it would make it clear what the question is concerned with, and having more tags is not very helpful in this case.